# How to enter one html textbox as a php array with each line being a new value?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, loops

I have a html text box that submits to a php script. I want the php to be able to loop through each entry in the html text box, which each entry being one line in the text box.

Multiple text boxes will not work as the user should be able to copy and paste into the form.

How can html/php distinguish between lines of input and enter them into an array to be looped through?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I assume since you're talking about multiple lines of input in one box you mean a textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
$input = explode("\n", $textdata);
```

$input will then be an array of the text from $textdata broken up by each newline.  Then...

```
foreach($input as $line)
{
//process the $line of text as needed.
}
```

Comment: Definitely a case of personal taste, but unless you're using $input more than once, you can just use `foreach(explode("\n", $textdata) as $line)`. But that's just me being pedantic!